# Understanding unicode in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I have script like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
var1 = '1F1EB 1F1F7'
var1 = re.sub(r' ', r'\\U000', var1)
var1 = r'\U000' + var1
var2 = '\U0001F1EB\U0001F1F7'
if var1 == var2:
    print('true')
print(type(var1))
print(var1)
print(type(var2))
print(var2)

Output:
<class 'str'>
\U0001F1EB\U0001F1F7
<class 'str'>
```

Input variable is `var1`, but I need to make it equal to `var2`. `var1` never equal `var2` in this case. What do i need to make them equal?

Expecting
Output:

```
<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\U0001F1EB` in a string literal is being interpreted and replaced by the appropriate Unicode character as part of the parsing process. I.e. writing `'\U0001F1EB\U0001F1F7'` and writing `''` are exactly the same thing, just alternative ways to express it. Programmatically constructing a string which contains the text "\U0001F1EB" isn't the same thing, it's just the text "\U0001F1EB".

What you want is to turn the hex number `1F1EB` into the Unicode character with that codepoint. You can do this by turning the number into a decimal and passing it to [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr):

```
chr(int('1F1EB', 16))
```

Doing this for both numbers creates the correct Unicode sequence for the French flag:

```
>>> chr(int('1F1EB', 16)) + chr(int('1F1F7', 16))
''
```

So, more programmatically:

```
>>> var1 = '1F1EB 1F1F7'
>>> ''.join(chr(int(i, 16)) for i in var1.split())
''
```